# Organizar os dados de um data binding em uma tabela

Tags: html, html5, vue.js, tabela-html

Estou tentando pegar os dados através de um data-binding e montar uma tabela (do bootstrap) usando um V-for, porém não acontece como eu esperava.

Estrutura da tabela:

```
<table class="table table-borderless">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">ID do pedido</th>
   <th scope="col">Nome</th>
   <th scope="col">Valor do pedido</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td scope="col" v-for="ID in DadosSucesso.Id" :key="ID.Id">{{ DadosSucesso.Id }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td scope="col" v-for="NOME in DadosSucesso.Nome" :key="NOME.Nome"> {{ DadosSucesso.Nome }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td scope="col" v-for="VALOR in DadosSucesso.Valor" :key="VALOR.Valor">$ {{ DadosSucesso.Valor }}</td>
  </tr>
```

Objetos que eu tento retornar:

```
data() {
  return {
    DadosSucesso: {
      Id: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
      Nome: ['João', 'Ramires', 'Lukas'],
      Valor: [ 22, 30, 97],
    }
  }  
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu gostaria que ficasse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que estou vendo, você está usando um objeto, cujo cada valor é um array, que por sua vez tem o mesmo tamanho em cada propriedade.

A solução que eu daria para isso seria contar a quantidade de valores existente em um dos items e, num loop com `v-for`, acessar esses valores pelo índice.

No `VUE` você pode usar números no `v-for` para criar um número de iterações.

Por exemplo:

```
v-for="i in 10"
```

O exemplo acima criará uma iteração de `1`a `10`. No caso da versão 2.0 >=, a iteração sempre começará pelo `1`, e não pelo `0`.

Como vamos iterar sobre o seu objeto que têm `arrays` e precisamos começar do `0`, poderíamos usar o par "chave valor" para obter a iteração a partir do `0`.

Assim:

```
v-for="(valor, chave) in 10"
```

Nesse caso, `valor` iria do `1` ao `10`, e `chave` do `0` ao `9`.

Com essas informações, podemos iterar sobre o seu objeto. Precisamos agpegar o `length` (o tamanho do array) de um dos items do seu objeto para usá-lo na iteração. **A ideia aqui é obter o valor de cada campo pelo índice do `array`.**

No exemplo abaixo, eu peguei `length` do `array` da propriedade `Id`.

Veja:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app', 
  data: {
    dados: {
      Id: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
      Nome: ['João', 'Ramires', 'Lukas'],
      Valor: [ 22, 30, 97],
    }
  }
})


console.log(app)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>

    <table class="table table-borderless">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID do pedido</th>
                <th scope="col">Nome</th>
                <th scope="col">Valor do pedido</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(_, k) in dados.Id.length">
                <td>{{ dados.Id[k] }}</td>
                <td>{{ dados.Nome[k] }}</td>
                <td>{{ dados.Valor[k] }}</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>


</div>
```

Comment: **Observação**: Adapte a solução ao seu caso. Eu posso ter trocado o nome de uma ou outra variável, mas a resposta funciona ;)

Answer (score -1):

Olá, vc está passando o mesmo obj do For.

Tente assim:

```
<tr>
   <td scope="col" v-for="ID in DadosSucesso.Id" :key="ID.Id">{{ ID }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td scope="col" v-for="NOME in DadosSucesso.Nome" :key="NOME.Nome"> {{ NOME }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td scope="col" v-for="VALOR in DadosSucesso.Valor" :key="VALOR.Valor">$ {{ VALOR }}</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Sim, dessa forma irei mostrar apenas um dado do array por vez. Mas a tabela ainda n fica da forma que eu gostaria. por exemplo, na primeira linha fica: 1 2 3, isso deveria ficar na primeira coluna..